# Is it possible to transfer tokens from one Multisig Wallet address to another Multisig Wallet?

Tags: tokens, wallets, multisignature, wallet-transfer

First, the multisign wallet has a number of tokens which I want to transfer to another Multisig wallet. 
Is it possible? If yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, it is possible, yes, but it depends on which multisig wallet contract you are using.

Not all mutlisig wallets support ERC20 transfers.
Here's an example of one that does support ERC20: https://github.com/BitGo/eth-multisig-v2

Basically, what has to happen is that wallet contract needs to call the token contract to transfer tokens to another address.

Comment: Yes. Right now I am working on the same contract which you've mentioned. But the problem is that I am minting tokens from token contract to This multisign wallet. Then I am trying to approve another address to spend that funds. But that contract is not able to deposit the approved token.

Comment: just so i understand, this is the flow you want: `token contract -> multisig contract -> approve another address to spend tokens from multisig`?

Comment: the multisig contract might need a `setOwner` function if that's the case.